# Summernote airmode in a form textarea?

Tags: javascript, forms, summernote

Does anyone know a way to use airMode with summernote, but correctly have it work with a form? For some reason, when I use airMode,

```
<textarea name="comments" class="summernote" placeholder="Write your feedback here"></textarea>
```

And js:

```
$('.summernote').summernote({airMode:true});
```

For some reason this only submits correctly when airmode is turned off.